# Declarative (CAML) BusinessData field

Tags: custom-list, external-content-type, list-template, external-data-column, caml

I am trying to create a List template definition declaratively (using CAML) which includes a External Data column and several secondary columns.

I created a custom list via the UI and exported the schema XML, trimmed out everything I didn't need, and that worked. I was able to install that schema and declaratively provision new list instances based on it.

However, when I tried to create & deploy a new list template definition from scratch, based on what I'd learned, it fails with a *Failed to do column assignments for list "List Name"* error in the ULS log. All that's really different is the LOB system, BDC model, field names, and view definitions.

Here is the XML for the list template; please advise as to what you see wrong. I cannot find any meaningful difference between this schema and the one that works.

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
      Title="Publications"
      EnableContentTypes="FALSE"
      FolderCreation="FALSE"
      ModeratedList="TRUE"
      DraftVersionVisibility="2"
      DisableAttachments="TRUE"
      Direction="$Resources:Direction;"
      Url="Lists/PublicationsListTemplate"
      BaseType="0">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01">
        <Folder TargetName="Item" />
      </ContentTypeRef>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field Type="BusinessData"
             DisplayName="News Item"
             Required="TRUE"
             ID="{3E43E68F-D992-42ED-B1E3-083AA0211297}"
             StaticName="News_x0020_Item"
             Name="News_x0020_Item"
             BaseRenderingType="Text"
             SystemInstance="{system instance}"
             EntityNamespace="{entity namespace}"
             EntityName="{entity name}"
             BdcField="Title"
             Profile="/_layouts/ActionRedirect.aspx?EntityNamespace={entity namesapce}&amp;EntityName={entity name}&amp;LOBSystemInstanceName={system instance}&amp;ItemID="
             HasActions="True"
             SecondaryFieldBdcNames="3%207%2013%2018%20ID%20Source%20Organization%20PublicationStatus%2010"
             RelatedField="NewsItemsAggregatorItemID"
             SecondaryFieldWssNames="14%207%2017%2033%20Item_x0020_ID%20Source%20Source_x0020_Org%20Source_x0020_Publish_x0020_Statu%2011"
             RelatedFieldBDCField=""
             RelatedFieldWssStaticName="NewsItemsAggregatorItemID"
             SecondaryFieldsWssStaticNames="14%207%2017%2033%20Item_x0020_ID%20Source%20Source_x0020_Org%20Source_x0020_Publish_x0020_Statu%2011"/>
      <Field Type="Note" DisplayName="NewsItemsAggregatorItemID" StaticName="NewsItemsAggregatorItemID" Name="NewsItemsAggregatorItemID" Hidden="TRUE" BdcField="ID" ID="{895E0330-957F-4893-837B-2168D43F2328}" ReadOnly="TRUE"/>
      <Field Type="Note" DisplayName="Item ID" StaticName="Item_x0020_ID" Name="Item_x0020_ID" BdcField="ID" ID="{1CD44DF3-80B7-4C61-B78E-774FA768559C}" ReadOnly="TRUE" />
      <Field Type="Note" DisplayName="Source" StaticName="Source" Name="Source" BdcField="Source" ID="{44E04BA2-4A41-4566-93CF-5015B500AE2C}" ReadOnly="TRUE"/>
      <Field Type="Note" DisplayName="Source Org" StaticName="Source_x0020_Org" Name="Source_x0020_Org" BdcField="Organization" ID="{B7C90E67-089D-4030-AFE6-5A027D1BABB8}" ReadOnly="TRUE"/>
      <Field Type="Note" DisplayName="Source Publish Status" StaticName="Source_x0020_Publish_x0020_Statu" Name="Source_x0020_Publish_x0020_Statu" BdcField="PublicationStatus" ID="{D6B9BCC1-33E5-4FB7-A34F-EBE9E9C6928C}" ReadOnly="TRUE"/>
    </Fields>
    <Views>
      <!--snip-->
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <!--snip-->
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your **only** issue, but it seems to me like your `SecondaryFieldBdcNames` and `SecondaryFieldWssNames` attributes have been encoded too many times.

These should be a list of the additional fields that you wish to bring through, separated by `:`.

So in your situation, it appears as if this should be:

```
SecondaryFieldBdcNames="ID:Source:Organization:PublicationStatus"
SecondaryFieldWssNames="Item_x0020_ID:Source:Source_x0020_Org:Source_x0020_Publish_x0020_Statu"
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: The colon-delimited format was true for MOSS 2007, but in SP 2010 it uses a different format.